# Laravel Eloquent: how to get related records via whereHas() method?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

For example, I can check every post with concrete date.

```
$users = User::whereHas('posts', function($q){
    $q->where('created_at', '>=', '2015-01-01 00:00:00');
})->get();
```

But suppose, what to do, if I want to compare a post model date (created_at) with the date attribute of user model?

For example:

```
$users = User::whereHas('posts', function($q){
    $q->where('created_at', '>=', ** $user->customDate ** ← look this);
})->get();
```

upd.
I use Eloquent outside of Laravel.

Comment: Is customDate a field in the users table?

Comment: yes, MySQL DATE field type

Comment: what's the point? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: For example, I want to get all posts at concrete day, which defined for concrete User.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a **raw expression** on the Eloquent sub query, by using `$q->whereRaw`.

In your example:

```
$users = User::whereHas('posts', function($q){
    $q->whereRaw("created_at >= users.customDate");
})->get();
```

Unlike `DB::raw`, this can be used without Laravel's dependency injection of `Illuminate\Database` facade.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your users table is just called `users` you can use `DB::raw()` to reference a value like you would in a normal query:

```
$users = User::whereHas('posts', function($q){
    $q->where('created_at', '>=', DB::raw('users.customDate'));
})->get();
```

Don't forget to either import the `DB` facade or just change it to `\DB::raw(...)`.

If you're using this outside of Laravel and don't have facades you can cut out the middleman and do:

```
$q->where('created_at', '>=', new Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression(('users.customDate'));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm, your method will be work in this situation? ScheduledEvent::find(1)->orders->where('dateFrom','=', ORDER_CUSTOM_DATE);

Comment: @Stanislav What?!?

Comment: It's a similar task, where need to get records from related orders table via concrete order.customDate in where condition.

Comment: And I have a problem - I use Eloquent outside of Laravels and don't  have facades and a method raw() of Database manager. Maybe you know other solution?

Comment: Sorry about that. With you tagging the question with `Laravel` I assumed you were using laravel. I'm assuming you have the whole `Illuminate\Database` package?

Comment: Yes, I have. But I dont have facades.